# How to fix vscode warning module not installed when using pnpm

Tags: pnpm

```
mkdir a-1 && cd a-1
pnpm init
pnpm i eslint --save-dev
code .
```

I opened this project in vscode on windows 10 and vscode showed these warnings.

```
Module '.pnpm' is extraneous
Module '@eslint/eslintrc' is extraneous
Module 'eslint-scope' is extraneous
Module 'eslint-utils' is extraneous
Module 'eslint' is not installed
```

[image: warning]

I know this doesn't affect the project, but is there any way to go about hiding this warning.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open the settings menu (`Ctrl+,` - Windows / `Cmd+,` - Mac), and navigate to the `Npm: Package Manager` field. Change the value in the dropdown to pnpm.

Afterwards, open the command palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P,` - Windows / `Cmd+Shift+P,` - Mac) and choose `Developer: Reload Window`.

Comment: Still not working for me on Windows using pnpm via WSL. Will update if I find the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't resolve with the answer showed here. I opened Settings -> TypeScript -> Change "
Controls if TypeScript launches a dedicated server to more quickly handle syntax related operations, such as computing code folding." from "auto" to "always" and it solved my problem.

I have no warnings anymore.

Comment: I had a similar issue and this solved it for me as well. I went to **Settings**, searched for `typescript controls` and then under **TypeScript > Tsserver: Use Syntax Server** changed `auto` to `always`. In my case it couldn't find `@types/node` or `@types/jest`.

Comment: This did solve things on Windows for me. However, when using *always* instead of *auto* meant it would "Use a lighter weight syntax server to handle all IntelliSense operations. This syntax server can only provide IntelliSense for opened files." Not having IntelliSense across project is not worth this work around. Not sure of an alternate solution, but wanted to share the impact.

Comment: "TypeScript > Tsserver: Use Syntax Server changed auto to always" worked for me

Comment: To me, either "always" or "never" worked. Only "auto" shows those warnings.